# 2 Laravel 8 Apps with own Packages, Providers & Cache, but shared App Classes

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-8, php-7.4

I would like to run 2 Laravel 8 apps. Both should have their own packages, providers, controllers & cache, but Commands, Models, Exception, .env & Conifg should use the same.
I have the following structure:

```
/main/ <- Laravel Main Package with Models, etc
/sub/ <- 2nd Laravel Package
/.env
```

The composer.json of the sub app:

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Console\\": "./../main/app/Console/",
        "App\\Exceptions\\": "./../main/app/Exceptions/",
        "App\\Http\\": "app/Http/",
        "App\\Models\\": "./../main/app/Models/",
        "App\\Providers\\": "app/Providers/"
    }
},
```

My bootstrap\app.php:

```
//...
if (!class_exists('Application')) {
    class Application extends OriginApplication
    {
        /**
         * Get the path to the application configuration files.
         *
         * @param  string  $path Optionally, a path to append to the config path
         * @return string
         */
        public function configPath($path = '')
        {
            return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'../main/config'.($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path : $path);
        }
    }
}

//...

$app->useEnvironmentPath(
    dirname(__DIR__, 2)
);
```

It works also so far that the .env is taken correctly, but with the classes from the main are not loaded, it comes `Undefined namespace 'Console'` and `Unable to detect application namespace`.
Does anyone know how I can best implement my plan?

Comment: Please share more details, like code that helps to understand and reproduce your problem

Comment: The problem is, that this not work. Laravel returns `Unable to detect application namespace`. @NicoHaase

`        "App\\Console\\": "./../main/app/Console/",
        "App\\Exceptions\\": "./../main/app/Exceptions/",
         "App\\Models\\": "./../main/app/Models/",
 `

Answer (score 0):

I created Symlinks.

For example
`sub/app/Console/` Symlink to `main/app/Console/`

And now the project in the folder sub use the `app/Console/` files of the project in the folder main.